# Most appropriate term for round and x-marker on a (scientific) chart?

Tags: terminology, technical, science

In a research paper, I'd like to refer to some specific markers on a chart. One marker looks like an x, and the other one is small circle.

What would be proper terms? Circular marker and x-marker?

Comment: Usually the color varies as well, and you can then say, "the red circle" or "the blue cross"

Comment: @Jim: In this case the color doesn't vary.

Comment: Cross and circle/dot sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Cross and Rondel - although this is not commonly used in day to day English.  In the military (airforce) a rondel is the simple insignia on the side of aircraft.  I believe it comes from French and is the diminutive of "round".

Comment: *[Roundel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roundel#Noun)* may be more applicable than *[rondel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rondel#Noun)*

Comment: @jwpat7 you should write that up!